# PowerShell. Clear previous Read-Host

Tags: powershell

I have the following code in which the user has to enter either Y or N. If it's ENTER or anything else it requests again. The request is made every time on the same line.

My problem is that after I enter a wrong answer, when I'm prompted again I have to write over my previous answer.
I've tried clearing the keyboard buffer before Read-Host with no luck. I don't want to use Clear-Host or a new line, it has to be on the same line.
My question is, can I have a clean line after a wrong answer?

```
function clrkb
{
    while($Host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable)
    {
        $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey() | Out-Null
    }
}
$y_temp +=1;
do
{
    clrkb
    [Console]::SetCursorPosition(2,$y_temp);write-host Is this a service job? Y/N -f Magenta;[Console]::SetCursorPosition(29,$y_temp);$sj = read-host
}until($sj -eq "Y" -or $sj -eq "N")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function clrkb{
    while(
        $Host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable){$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey() | Out-Null
    }
}
$y_temp +=1;
do{
    clrkb
    [Console]::SetCursorPosition(2,$y_temp);write-host Is this a service job? Y/N -f Magenta;[Console]::SetCursorPosition(29,$y_temp);[Console]::Write(' ' * [Console]::WindowWidth);[Console]::SetCursorPosition(29,$y_temp);$sj = read-host
}until($sj -eq "Y" -or $sj -eq "N")
```

Use spaces to overwrite wrong answer.

Maybe `[Console]::WindowWidth` is not always big enough, so `$sj.length` can be used instead.

```
function clrkb{
    while(
        $Host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable){$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey() | Out-Null
    }
}
$y_temp +=1;
$sj='';
do{
    clrkb
    [Console]::SetCursorPosition(2,$y_temp);write-host Is this a service job? Y/N -f Magenta;[Console]::SetCursorPosition(29,$y_temp);[Console]::Write(' ' * $sj.length);[Console]::SetCursorPosition(29,$y_temp);$sj = read-host
}until($sj -eq "Y" -or $sj -eq "N")
```

Comment: `cls` clears it but I have more than one questions like this and I don't want to clear the host after each one. it might not be possible what I want.